disable chrome history in search bar
I like to define and use custom entries in Chrome browsing search engine site settings also as hotkeys for sites without any search functionality. I often use a single letter shortcut (for example 'd' to open google drive homepage). So rather than using a bookmark, simply open a new tab and type the shortcut and enter.
Problem however that this is not entirely predictable as chrome will sometimes assign priority to recently viewed websites that begin with the shortcut. A recent example would be for the shortcut 'p' assigned to google photos, is actually several entries down so that I need to micromanage this operation.
By clicking the 'X' next to the browsing history entry, this can be removed to restore the site setting shortcut, but only until the next browsing history entry that starts with 'p'. Is there a way to disable history from appearing in the search bar altogether?
history takes precedence
